# Determining Volume by rotation of a plane

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

a) What is the area of the region R between the graphs of $y= \sin x$ and $y=\sin ^2 x$ for $x \in [0; \frac{\pi}{2}]$

I found $a(R)= 1-\frac{\pi}{4}$

b) Let R be the region from question a). Rotating $R$ about the x-axis describes a solid S. Compute the volume of S

Thank you

Comment: Whoops, you're right...
Why ask then?

Comment: Yes, both I and Xiaolang made a mistake. The area of a circle of radius $r_1$ with a hole of radius $r_2$ is not the same as the area of a circle of radius $r_1 - r_2$. The idea is the same whether it's $\sin x^2$ or $\sin^2 x$. In the latter case the integration will be easier though.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė Ok thank you. Could you help me with a similar question here regarding the concept of a "mass" http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361342/mass-of-a-rectangle/361368?noredirect=1#comment776388_361368

Comment: yes. (the comment area isn't really for this. delete your comments after you've solved the problem and flag mine).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8333/discussion-between-user43418-and-karolis-juodel)

Answer (score 0):

just like the Riemann integrate definition 
you can put the area of the section as a contionous function $f(x)$

and then calculate the integration $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ it is just the volume

and in advance to calculate a rotating body's volume

the $f(x)$ can be written by the function in (a) as $f(x)=\pi g(x)^2$  ($g(x)$ acts as a "radius")

and the sums changes to $V=\pi \int_a^bg^2(x)dx$

in the OP's question ,the $g(x)$ is equals to $\sin x-\sin x^2$

Comment: But what is the exact expression of the integral. And what are the limits of the integral ?

Comment: @user43418 sorry i put the "send" button in accident and edit it later...

Comment: the $f(x)$ refer to the area of the section,the first formula is more common and fundamantal and the second formula especially used to calculate the rotating body's volume

Comment: @Xiaolang What is g ?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol g(x) is like a radius in the circle.

Comment: @Xiaolang And the limits of the integral are $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol In fact i was saying a universal method to solve this kind of problem...

Comment: @Xiaolang I am having a trouble with the integration because I have the following integral: $\int_{0}^{\pi /2} sin(x)sin(x^2)$

Comment: you are sure you didn't forget the symbol "+"? The wolframalpha tell me this integration is can't be calculate exactly..

Comment: @Xiaolang Well the volume is: $V(R)=\pi \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin x- \sin x^2)^2dx$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%280+to+pi%2F2%29+pi%28sin%28x%29-sin%28x%5E2%29%29%5E2

Comment: and if this integration can get a exact solution then the $\int \cos(x^2)$ can get too? i dont think it's possible...However it can due to my bad math study....

Comment: @Xiaolang I made a mistake. My professor told me it's $sin^2 x$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8332/discussion-between-user43418-and-xiaolang)